# Where is the "Default Wallpaper" wallpaper stored

Tags: desktop-background

I just upgraded to 14.04, and it's amazing. Obviously, I went to check out the new backgrounds and one caught my eye. It's an abstract blue design and is marked as one that changes throughout the day and its title is "Default Wallpaper". I really would like to find this wallpaper's file, but I can't.

If you are wondering, it looks like this:

[image: background]

I've checked in `/usr/share/backgrounds` and `/usr/share/wallpapers` but neither has them, just the picture wallpaper. Is there a special place that the ones that change are stored, or are they simply inaccessible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Indeed - this is part of an automatic picture changer consisting of three JPG's gradually cycling from one JPG to another over certain time-periods:

- 07:00 for one hour fixed at morning.jpg
- 08:00 for 5 hours - gradually transitioning from morning.jpg to bright-day.jpg,
- 13:00 for 5 hours - fixed at bright-day.jpg
- 19:00 for 6 hours - gradually transitioning from bright-day.jpg to good-night.jpg
- 00:00 for 5 hours - fixed at good-night.jpg
- 05:00 for 2 hours - gradually transitioning from good-night.jpg to morning.jpg

This is driven by an XML file located in the Adwaita theme folder `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/backgrounds/adwaita-timed.xml`

Have a look - you can use this XML as a template for your own wallpaper changer

[image]

Comment: To clarify, the JPEG files in question are located in `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/backgrounds` as well.

Answer (score 17):

I don't think this is a default wallpaper, or at least I don't have it.

You can get the location of your current wallpaper by executing `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri` as an user who has set this wallpaper.

I've never heard of "dynamic wallpapers" in Ubuntu so I hope this method still works for you.

Comment: It's the default wallpaper for Ubuntu GNOME 14.04, not for Unity.

Comment: I saw Unity on his screenshot so I was assuming he was running the 'normal' Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

The wallpaper always comes accompanied of a theme or in a package, in the case of these is the `gnome-themes-standard-data` package which has all the wallpapers:

```
[...]
/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/backgrounds/bright-day.jpg
/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/backgrounds/good-night.jpg
/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/backgrounds/morning.jpg
[...]
```

The complete list of all files in the packages can be found in the [package list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/gnome-themes-standard-data/filelist). The images correspond to the 3.12 version of Gnome 3 wallpapers.